# Social Tables API: Build room diagram for Wedding

Tags: social-tables

Our customers commonly build room diagrams for weddings. A typical Wedding room diagram contains two elements:

- Aligned or staggered round tables with chairs throughout the room (for guests).
- A Head table at one side of the room (for the wedding party).

I know that the Layout Automation Social Tables API endpoint can easily handle each of these cases when executed independently (but there could be overlap). Is it possible to use Layout Automation to build a diagram with both together (with proper positioning avoiding overlap)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout automation does not support multiple setup types at this time.